# How to I finish the "continue;" That i putted after the if statement?

Tags: android, touch, continue

I made a statement and if it is true it continues, I want to stop this "continue" and make another statement for example touchdown and touchup.

here is my code

```
private void updateRunning(float deltaTime) {
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();
    int len = touchEvents.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);

        if (event.type != TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP)
            continue;
        world.doodle.DOODLE_Y = 3;
        touchPoint.set(event.x, event.y);
        guiCam.touchToWorld(touchPoint);

        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(pauseBounds, touchPoint)) {
            Assets.clicks();
            state = GAME_PAUSED;
            return;
        }

    }

    world.update(deltaTime, game.getInput().getAccelX());
    if (world.score != lastScore) {
        lastScore = world.score;
        scoreString = "" + lastScore;
    }
    if (world.state == World.WORLD_STATE_NEXT_LEVEL) {
        state = GAME_LEVEL_END;
    }
    if (world.state == World.WORLD_STATE_GAME_OVER) {
        state = GAME_OVER;
        if (lastScore >= Settings.highscores[4])
            scoreString = "new highscore: " + lastScore;
        else
            scoreString = "score: " + lastScore;
        Settings.addScore(lastScore);
        Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little confused by what you are asking, but perhaps an `else if`?

```
if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
    /* do something for TOUCH_UP event */
} else if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {
    /* do something for TOUCH_DOWN event */
} else {
    /* do something else */
}
```

You can't *stop* a `continue` after you execute it.

Comment: so I shouldn't use the continue statement?

Comment: `continue` is usually used in a loop if you want to stop the execution of the loop on the current item and process the next one. It's a totally valid construction, depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `break;` where you want it to stop.